# How can I set a validation on HTML on Ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now, I am asked to set a validation on HTML on Ruby project but I don't know how to set a validation on HTML. ( I only know about the validation on model and express the error message on HTML)

If anyone knows how to implement the validation please tell me anything.

**What I what to achieve.**

1. EMOJI check
   *①I want to check if the form has an invalid letter like Emoji in the form.*
   *②If the form has an invalid letter like Emoji, I want it to be deleted instantly.*
2. implement the length validation like min: 8, max:255 validation.

the slim file looks like this.

```
.card.card-outline.card-warning
  .card-header.text-center
    h3 = "#{sitename}reception"
  .card-body
    p.login-box-msg.mb-3 write the description below
    = bootstrap_form_with model: @repair, url: fc_receptions_path, layout: :horizontal, label_col: 'col-6 d-none text-right', control_col: 'col-12' do |f|
      = f.hidden_field :id
      = f.fields_for :customer do |c|
        = c.hidden_field :id
        .row
          .col-6
            span.badge.badge-danger.float-left.mr-1 required
            = c.label :name
            = c.text_field :name
          .col-6
            span.badge.badge-danger.float-left.mr-1 required
            = c.label :tel
            = c.telephone_field :tel
            = c.label :email
            = c.email_field :email
        .row
          .col-12.mt-2
            .text-center
              = f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary'

= javascript_include_tag '//jpostal-1006.appspot.com/jquery.jpostal.js'
```

Any kinds of comment like it is impossible to do something like above or any other plans are really appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use minlength  ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength ) , maxlength ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength ) and pattern ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern ) in your HTML and the browser will validate the fields before sending the information to the server.

Comment: While @javiyu's comment could be useful the "deleted instantly" portion sounds like you are going to need to add some javascript.